# PowerShell Script for Importing .reg File to Remote Computer Hanging

Tags: powershell, foreach, registry, invoke-command

I'm using the following script to import a .reg file to remote computers. What I need to happen is the following:

1. Connect to the remote computer and kill a running process if it's running.
2. Copy a .reg key file from a Network Share location to the remote computer.
3. Import the copied .reg key to the remote computer's registry.'
4. Delete the copied .reg key file from the remote computer.
5. Start the process that was killed at the beginning.

Now I'm relatively new to PowerShell scripting and the script I have is part cannibalized from scripts I've found searching the internet and my PowerShell Cookbook.

What happens when I run the script is that it'll connect to the remote computer and kill the process, but then the script gets hung up, and doesn't do steps 2-5. It's not throwing out any errors either. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
#Variables
$Computers = Get-Content C:\computer.txt
$LocalRegFileName = "regfile.reg"
$HostedRegFile = "\\NETWORK-SHARE\Folder\Folder\regfile.reg"
$ProcessName = "Process"
$FilePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\$ProcessName.exe"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer {
        Get-Process -Name $ProcessName | Stop-Process -Force
    }

    $NewFile = "\\$Computer\C'$\TEMP\$LocalRegFileName"
    New-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ItemType directory -Path \\$Computer\C$\TEMP
    Copy-Item $HostedRegFile -Destination $NewFile
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" -ArgumentList "/s C:\TEMP\$LocalRegFileName"
    }

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        Remove-Item "C:\TEMP\$LocalRegFileName"
    }

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        Start-Process -FilePath "$FilePath\$ProcessName.exe"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use Group Policy Preferences to update registry values? (Running `regedit.exe` from a script is a very clumsy approach, IMO.)

Comment: Because the .reg file I'm attempting to import has settings for an application and it has around 200 values that I need to import. If I have to I can do it that way, but I'd still like to know what I'm doing wrong with the script.

Comment: There's an error on the line `$NewFile = `. (I don't think the path `\\$Computer\C'$` exists.)

Comment: A couple of things don't look right.  To pass your local variables to the remote sessions, you will need to use the `using` modifier.  For example: `Remove-Item "C:\TEMP\$using:LocalRegFileName"`.  Also, even with the variables working, `"$FilePath\$ProcessName.exe"` is going to expand to: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\$ProcessName.exe\Process.exe"`.  You might want to remove all of the variables and hard-code the values until you are convinced the script works correctly, then 'simplify' it from there.